# What should I do about mold until the leak feeding it gets fixed?

Tags: leak, ceiling, mold

About three weeks ago I noticed a leak on the ceiling of my studio apartment. When it began it was just a leak, a few days later it began to get dark-stained all around it and now it's covered in a black thing that I suppose is some kind of mould. I reported this to my landlord as soon as it began bit I still have one more week to wait until someone comes to fix it.

It looks so disgusting, it's on the kitchen area and I would like to know what to do until it gets fixed, is there anything I can do?

Today I took this cardboard box and put it over the leak to cover it. I fixed it to the ceiling around the stain of mould with a bit of sellotape. Now at least I don't see it but I don't know if maybe this is going to make things worse.

Comment: What's above your apartment?  Can you get the leak stopped?

Answer (score 1):

If the wet area dries out faster than the leak, the mold will not grow.  Drill a hole to drain the water quicker.  Set up a fan to blow air over the area to dry it.  Don't cover it, that will just keep it wetter and accelerate the mold.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the mold off with a bleach/water mixture, or some other anti-fungal cleaner.

Mold needs three things to grow: moisture, organic material, and mold spores.

Mold spores are everywhere, so try to keep the area clean and dry.